# Adding header name to row columns with google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

Is it possible to change the column headers from A, B to lets say name , email ?Then you could take advantage of the native sorting capability of the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the letters assigned to the columns is not supported in Google Sheets (or Excel for that matter).

However, the behavior that you're describing can be easily achieved by using the "Freeze" functionality.

Simply add the column names that you want in the top row, then select the entire row (by clicking on the number 1 on the left side of the screen), and then click `View` > `Freeze` > `1 row`.

You should now be able to sort the data in the columns without the header labels moving around.